# DNS Cache Poisoning With Multiple Requests

Tags: dns

I am trying to understand this DNS cache poisoning from a textbook.

[image]

Is it the case that the server does not check any pending requests for a given domain and will send all of the n "same" requests to the DNS Lookup?

If the attacker manages to guess one Query ID and poison the cache why don't the other legitimate DNS replies overwrite the poisoned cache when they come back?